# Redirected to Default path before getting API Data from Redux on protected routes

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks, react-router-dom

Protected Route redirected to the login page, before getting API data from the redux, Is there any way of getting data first and then move to the next component, instead of redirecting to the default path ?

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { Navigate } from "react-router-dom";

import * as userActionCreators from "./redux/actionCreators/userActionCreators";
import { Spinner } from "./components/spinner/spinner";
import { routePaths } from "./utils/constants/routePaths";

const ProtectedRoute = ({ children }) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const userError = useSelector((state) => state.userReducer.userError);
  const currentUserResponse = useSelector(
    (state) => state.userReducer.currentUserResponse
  );
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(
    currentUserResponse?.id ? false : true
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!currentUserResponse?.id) {
      dispatch(userActionCreators.currentUser());
    }
  }, [dispatch]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (currentUserResponse?.id || userError) {
      setLoading(false);
    }
  }, [currentUserResponse, userError]);

  if (loading) return <Spinner height="10%" width="10%" />;

  if (!currentUserResponse?.id) {
    debugger;
    return <Navigate to={routePaths.landing()} replace />;
  }

  return children;
};

export default ProtectedRoute;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set `loading` to `true` in `useEffect` before using `dispatch` and after `dispatch` set it to `false`.

And check in `return` for `loading` if `loading` is `true` then show loading... and if it is `false` only then `Navigate` like below:

Set loading in `useEffect`

```
 useEffect(() => {
    setLoading(true)
    if (!currentUserResponse?.id) {
      dispatch(userActionCreators.currentUser());
    }
    setLoading(false)
  }, [dispatch]);
```

Check for `loading` in `return`

```
if(loading) {
   return (<h1>Loading...</h1>)
}

return <Navigate to={routePaths.landing()} replace />;
```